# Tibco Spotfire basic authentication with cross domain ajax call

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, basic-authentication, spotfire

I am creating a client side session using cross domain ajax call to Spotfire server. For authentication I am using basic authentication method. When I make my request through Postman with `Authorization` header and value `'Basic ' + btoa('user:password')` it send correct header and start a new session, whereas in web browser it shows error as

> NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed -
>   http://server-path/GetJavaScriptApi.ashx?Version=8.0

&

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://server-path/GetJavaScriptApi.ashx?Version=8.0.
>
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

This was because in cross domain ajax call first `OPTIONS` request is made followed by `POST/GET`, to overcome this I made `dataType: "jsonp"` in my ajax call. Now GET calls are  working but now gives me a new error:

> The resource from
>   “http://server-path/GetJavaScriptApi.ashx?Version=8.0&callback=jQuery111107482621169238032_1487159470493&_=1487159470494”
>   was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff).

Ajax code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'https://server-path/GetJavaScriptApi.ashx?Version=8.0', 
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,              
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", Basic ' + btoa('user:password'));
      xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", 'text/plain');
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (jsonData) {
        console.log(jsonData);                  
    },
});
```

Call to `https://server-path/GetJavaScriptApi.ashx?Version=8.0` return javascipt as response after successful authentication

Please help to resolve.. Thanks